# Does frequentist statistics support the use of priors?

Tags: bayesian, prior, frequentist

My understanding of the main difference between Frequentist vs Bayesian stats is that the former treats parameters as variables with **fixed** but unknown values whereas the latter treats them as **random** variables.

From that perspective, I get the impression that priors (and posteriors) would only make sense in Bayesian statistics. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, but there is a lot of overlap in practise.eg frequentist ridge regression ~ Bayesian linear regression with normal priors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in the sense that in Bayesian statistics the space of parameters $\Theta$ is endowed with the structure of a probability space $(\Theta, \mathcal{A},\pi)$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and $\pi$ a probability (prior) so it make sense to ask questions of the form
$$
B\in \mathcal{A},\quad \int_B f(\theta)\pi(d\theta)
$$

Where this would not make sense in a frequentist setting.